# how to submit pyspark job with dependency on google dataproc cluster

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using google dataproc cluster to run spark job, the script is in python.

When there is only one script (test.py for example), i can submit job with the following command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster analyse ./test.py
```

But now test.py import modules from other scripts written by myself, how can i specify the dependency in the command ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `--py-files` option mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a structure as

```
- maindir - lib - lib.py
          - run - script.py
```

You could include additional files with the --files flag or the --py-files flag

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=clustername --region=regionname --files /lib/lib.py /run/script.py
```

and you can import in script.py as

```
from lib import something
```

However, I am not aware of a method to avoid the tedious process of adding the file list manually. Please check [Submit a python project to dataproc job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386462/submit-a-python-project-to-dataproc-job) for a more detailed explaination