# Submit a Python project to Dataproc job

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a python project, whose folder has the structure

```
main_directory - lib - lib.py
               - run - script.py
```

`script.py` is

```
from lib.lib import add_two
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('yarn') \
    .appName('script') \
    .getOrCreate()

print(add_two(1,2))
```

and `lib.py` is

```
def add_two(x,y):
    return x+y
```

I want to launch as a Dataproc job in GCP. I have checked online, but I have not understood well how to do it. I am trying to launch the script with

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --region=$REGION \
  run/script.py
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
from lib.lib import add_two
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.lib'
```

Could you help me on how I should do to launch the job on Dataproc? The only way I have found to do it is to remove the absolute path, making this change to `script.py`:

```
 from lib import add_two
```

and the launch the job as

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --region=$REGION \
  --files /lib/lib.py \
  /run/script.py
```

However, I would like to avoid the tedious process to list the files manually every time.

Following the suggestion of @Igor, to pack in a zip file I have found that

```
zip -j --update -r libpack.zip /projectfolder/* && spark-submit --py-files libpack.zip /projectfolder/run/script.py
```

works. However, this puts all files in the same root folder in libpack.zip, so if there were files with the same names in subfolders this would not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

To zip the dependencies -

```
cd base-path-to-python-modules
zip -qr deps.zip ./* -x script.py
```

Copy deps.zip to hdfs/gs. Use uri when submitting the job as shown below.

Submit a python project (pyspark) using Dataproc' Python connector

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1.gapic.transports import (
    job_controller_grpc_transport)

region = <cluster region>
cluster_name = <your cluster name>
project_id = <gcp-project-id>

job_transport = (
    job_controller_grpc_transport.JobControllerGrpcTransport(
        address='{}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443'.format(region)))
dataproc_job_client = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient(job_transport)

job_file = <gs://bucket/path/to/main.py or hdfs://file/path/to/main/job.py>

# command line for the main job file
args = ['args1', 'arg2']

# required only if main python job file has imports from other modules
# can be one of .py, .zip, or .egg. 
addtional_python_files = ['hdfs://path/to/deps.zip', 'gs://path/to/moredeps.zip']

job_details = {
    'placement': {
        'cluster_name': cluster_name
    },
    'pyspark_job': {
        'main_python_file_uri': job_file,
        'args': args,
        'python_file_uris': addtional_python_files
    }
}

res = dataproc_job_client.submit_job(project_id=project_id,
                                     region=region, 
                                     job=job_details)
job_id = res.reference.job_id

print(f'Submitted dataproc job id: {job_id}')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for the Dataproc to recognize python project directory structure we have to zip the directory from where the import starts.

example: if we have python project directory structure as this — dir1/dir2/dir3/script.py
and if the import is `from dir2.dir3 import script as sc` then we have to zip dir2 and pass the zip file as --py-files during spark submit.

```
zip -r dir2 dir2

--py-files dir2.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve project structure when submitting Dataroc job then you should package your project into a `.zip` file and specify it in [`--py-files`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark#--py-files) parameter when submitting a job:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --region=$REGION \
  --py-files lib.zip \
  run/script.py
```

To create zip archive you need to run script:

```sh
cd main_directory/
zip -x run/script.py -r libs.zip .
```

Refer to [this blog post](https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f) for more details on how to package dependencies in zip archive for PySpark jobs.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. However, how to call the add_two function from the script.py file?

Comment: I think that you need to add `-r` option when creating zip archive and it will preserve project structure - see updated answer.