# Dataproc doesn't import Python module stored in Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-import, google-cloud-dataproc

I have following structure on Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket :

```
gs://my_bucket/py_scripts/
    wrapper.py
    mymodule.py
    _init__.py
```

I am running `wrapper.py` through Dataproc as a pyspark job and it imports `mymodule` using `import mymodule` at the start but the job is returning error saying `no module named mymodule` even though they are at the same path. This however works fine in the Unix environment.

Note that `_init__.py` is empty. Also tested `from mymodule import myfunc` but returns same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide your pyspark job submit command ? 
I suspect you are not passing "--py-files" params to provide other python files to job. Check for reference https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark . 
Dataproc will not assume files in same GS bucket as input to job.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using this job submit command - gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://mybucket/py_scripts/wrapper.py --step-id=01_python --workflow-template=wf_template --region europe-west1  -- (params) . So how should i pass the other mymodule.py in this command? And also what about multiple dependencies, like if mymodule.py imports another script mymodule2.py and so on.

Comment: You can zip files alternatively. Please check this stackoverflow question which discusses same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386462/submit-a-python-project-to-dataproc-job